# Find all duplicate minutes variable for batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

Ok so i have a folder of files such as below

```
ERROR WITH Position Post_20162602_022046.eml
ERROR WITH Position Post_20162602_032048.eml
ERROR WITH Position Post_20162602_042050.eml
ERROR WITH Position Post_20162602_052108.eml
ERROR WITH Position Post_20162602_062109.eml
ERROR WITH Position Post_20162602_012110.eml
ERROR WITH Position Post_20162602_012111.eml
ERROR WITH Position Post_20162602_012114.eml
ERROR WITH Position Post_20162602_012121.eml
EXCEPTION ERROR_20162602_034502.eml
EXCEPTION ERROR_20162602_072602.eml
INCOMPLETE MESSAGE_20162602_092345.eml
```

My goal is to use a .bat file to look at the HH:MM:SS (hours:minutes:seconds)
part of the file and to determine all the emails that came in at 01 21 in this example. However the var will change depending on the times that errors are encountered and the program might have to search for a different time...

The only constant in this problem is that the file times will be duplicated but i have no way of knowing how many times, how often or how much. so i need the .bat to see that the times are duplicated and then show me all the files that are duplicated.

I managed to find this code below but it looks at the files extension and has a constant `PATTERN` var

```
@Echo OFF

Set "Pattern=abcd"

For /R "C:\" %%# in (*.xml) Do (
Echo %%~nx# | FIND "%Pattern%" 1>NUL && (
    Set /A "Index+=1"
    Call Set "XML%%INDEX%%=%%~#"
    Echo Full Path: %%~#
    REM Echo FileName : %%~nx#
    REM Echo Directory: %%~p#
)
)

CLS
Echo XML1 = %XML1%
Echo XML2 = %XML2%

Pause&Exit
```

I read up on the `QGREP` command but it needs a constant as well. As i understand it.
[image: Image of the times i would like the .bat to find]

Comment: The image is of the times for example " 22 05 " and " 16 42 " the seconds don't matter.

Comment: You could input the pattern from command line parameters using `%~1` or such.

Comment: Is the goal to identify clusters that all came in within seconds of each other, or to sort into minute buckets?  If the former, then, for example, the first red box in your image should also include the previous four entries 220448, 220451, 220454, and 220459.

Comment: Minute buckets will be better. The system that sends the .eml files is running 24/7 so the files i want to look at will change between 00:00:00 to 23:59:59 at anytime. Then when an error occurs there will be a bunch of .eml files with the time 23:40:30 for example and i want to find those files with that exact time however, the time could be 23:41:00 or 22:30:40 or 07:00:58... to whatever between 00:00:00 to 23:59:59

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am afraid your request is confusing, so I rephrased the specifications this way:

There are several files with this file name format:

```
Any text_YYYYDDMM_HHMMSS.eml
```

Count the files accordingly to HHMM and report the names of the files when the count is greater than 1.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for %%a in (*.eml) do (
   for /F "tokens=3 delims=_" %%b in ("%%~Na") do (
      set "fileTime=%%b"
      for %%t in (!fileTime:~0^,4!) do (
         set /A "count[%%t]+=1"
         set names[%%t]=!names[%%t]! "%%a"
      )
   )
)

echo More than 1 message received at:
for /F "tokens=2,3 delims=[]=" %%a in ('set count[') do (
   if %%b gtr 1 (
      echo ------------------------
      for %%c in (!names[%%a]!) do (
         echo %%~c
      )
   )
)
```

Output example:

```
More than 1 message received at:
------------------------
ERROR WITH Position Post_20162602_012110.eml
ERROR WITH Position Post_20162602_012111.eml
ERROR WITH Position Post_20162602_012114.eml
ERROR WITH Position Post_20162602_012121.eml
```

If this is not what you want, please be clearer in your description.

Comment: Yes thanks, thats what i want : ) just added `pause` at the end of the script to see the output

Comment: So i tweaked it a bit and got what I want many thanks :)  `@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for %%a in (*.eml) do (
   for /F "tokens=3 delims=_" %%b in ("%%~Na") do (
      set "fileTime=%%b"
      for %%t in (!fileTime:~0^,4!) do (
         set /A "count[%%t]+=1"
         set names[%%t]=!names[%%t]! "%%a"
      )
   )
)

for /F "tokens=2,3 delims=[]=" %%a in ('set count[') do (
   if %%b gtr 1 (
      for %%c in (!names[%%a]!) do (
          type "%%~c" >> C:\output\%%~ci.eml
      )
   )
)

 `

Comment: I have no idea why the code got so messy... it works though