# Deleting files with more than 5 duplicates from a folder containing a bunch of duplicates

Tags: windows, batch-file, duplicates

Ok so this is driving me nuts but i'll try explain myself as well as I can :)

I have a folder of duplicates and non duplicates like below

```
1.txt
1.txt
1.txt
2.txt
2.txt
3.txt
3.txt
4.txt
4.txt
4.txt
4.txt
5.txt
6.txt
7.txt
7.txt
7.txt
7.txt
8.txt
```

Now I want to find only the duplicates of files that are more than 3, In this case that would be all the `7.txt` and `4.txt` files. BUT the files go on to `infinity.txt`

So there is no way i can pre-set the conditions. the script must recognize that there is more than 3 duplicates so i can extract those files.

--- Alright so i tried the script below which works well however it does not "extract" as mentioned above.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35790608/find-all-duplicate-minutes-variable-for-batch) is a link to a question I asked concerning this but I battled to explain it well enough.

```
`@echo off
 setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

 for %%a in (*.eml) do (
  for /F "tokens=3 delims=_" %%b in ("%%~Na") do (
   set "fileTime=%%b"
    for %%t in (!fileTime:~0^,4!) do (
     set /A "count[%%t]+=1"
     set names[%%t]=!names[%%t]! "%%a"
      )
   )
)

 for /F "tokens=2,3 delims=[]=" %%a in ('set count[') do (
  if %%b gtr 1 (
    for %%c in (!names[%%a]!) do (
      type "%%~c" >> C:\output\%%~ci.eml
      )
   )
)`
```

Comment: Just change `if %%b gtr 1` by `if %%b gtr 3`, or 5...

Comment: How can you have more than 1 `1.txt` in the same folder?

Comment: You will have to look at the link i included to understand exactly what I'm saying

Comment: Those aren't duplicate files in that other question. Those are multiple files that share the same prefix.

Answer (score 2):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

FOR %%a in (*.eml) DO (
FOR /F "tokens=3 delims=_" %%b IN ("%%~Na") DO (
  SET "fileTime=%%b"
  FOR %%t in (!fileTime:~0^,4!) DO (
     SET /A "count[%%t]+=1"
     SET names[%%t]=!names[%%t]! "%%a"
      )
   )
)

FOR /F "tokens=2,3,4 delims=[]=" %%a IN ('set count[') DO (
IF %%b gtr 3 (
   FOR %%c IN (!names[%%a]!) DO (
       TYPE "%%~c" >> C:\output\%%~ci.eml
      )
   )
)
```

I missed a token... thanks for the help guys. so the script is working now. It sends `.eml` files with more than 3 of the same prefixes to the `output` folder.

Comment: Wow! You just _"changed `if %%b gtr 1` by `if %%b gtr 3`"_, exactly as I said yesterday! The original code have not any missing token; the additional `%%c` token defined by `"tokens=2,3,4 ...` is cancelled by the posterior `FOR %%c` command